# Is there a way to convert a defined format of CSV file having intent and training phrases to RASA nlu.md file?

Tags: python, nlp, chatbot, rasa-nlu, rasa

Is there a way to create a CSV file with training phrases in it and convert the same to nlu.md format that is acceptable by Rasa.

This needs to be done for various intents with various training phrases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a way to do it using a simple script in python. 
Here is the link for the same.

https://github.com/lohithpro/csvtorasa

This will convert CSV file to Rasa acceptable nlu.md file.

The standard format to be followed while creating a CSV is shown in nlu_sample_format_for_conversion.csv file. This CSV file is converted to rasa format nlu.md file.

STEPS TO CREATE nlu.md file:

1. Download the whole repo.
2. Open nlu_sample_format_for_conversion.csv that was downloaded.
3. First rows consist of intent names. Add any number of intents in the first row.
4. The succeeding rows. i.e after the intent names row, add all your training phrases/sentences.
5. save the file
6. Open csvtorasa.py and call the function/method create_rasa_nlu(path, nlu_md_path). Don't forget to specify path to the CSV file using the path parameter, and path where the output nlu.md file needs to be created via the nlu_md_path parameter.